# How can I output a new line with `FORMATMESSAGE` in transact sql?

Tags: sql-server

The following code stats that, how many users that has created at least one post on a specific SE site.

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT
SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OwnerUserId) 
FROM Posts where OwnerUserId is not null)
PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('%s has \r\n %d users', DB_NAME(), @RowCount+1)
```

which basically works though, the `FORMATMESSAGE` part does not work as expected.

Usually, `\n` (in lots of systems and languages) and `\r\n` (mainly in MS systems) represent new line. I tried both, and even `/r/n`, none of them worked.

How can I output a new line with `FORMATMESSAGE` in transact sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the interpretation of `\r\n` as carriage return and line feed. SQL Server does interpret `\r\n` like this in some places, but the `FORMATMESSAGE` function is not one of them, so instead you need to use `CHAR(13)` and `CHAR(10)` which represents the the ASCII codes for Carriage Return (13) and Line Feed (10):

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT
SET @RowCount = (SELECT 10)
PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('%s has ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' %d users', DB_NAME(), @RowCount+1)
```

Or use a variable:

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT,
    @NewLine CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
SET @RowCount = (SELECT 10)
PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('%s has ' + @NewLine + ' %d users', DB_NAME(), @RowCount+1)
-- or
DECLARE @RowCount INT,
    @NewLine CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
SET @RowCount = (SELECT 10)
PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('%s has %s %d users', DB_NAME(), @NewLine, @RowCount+1)
```

Alternatively:

```
PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('%s has %s %d users', 
    DB_NAME(), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), @RowCount+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to remember that can be convenient in some places is that SQL Server strings can simply span multiple lines. So you can include your carriage returns right in the string without using any special characters in any case where that is the more readabile alternative.

```
PRINT FORMATMESSAGE(
'This is the first line: %s
And here is the second line: %s
And now the third: %s', 'First', 'Second', 'Third'
);
```

Output from this:

```
This is the first line: First 
And here is the second line: Second 
And now the third: Third
```